What happened to the testing documentation?
In the Craft 4.x documentation, at the bottom, there is a link to "Testing Craft", which points us to a somewhat useful overview of how to use Codeception within Craft to test our modifications to the system.
In the Craft 5.x documentation, no such link can be found. Sure... the docs have been "restructured", so it might be somewhere else now. But searching the docs, I can't find any mention of Codeception, or testing of any kind.
Is testing using Codeception no-longer documented/supported in Craft 5.x, or am I simply not good enough at searching the 5.x documentation?

We have been talking internally about switching test frameworks, so this section of the documentation is on hold while I find time to validate the recommended 4.x tooling in 5.x!
Feel free to ask in the #testing channel on Discord!
https://www.craftcms.com/community

Thank you. Appreciate it. Struggled quite a bit with the current setup, so a do-over/cleanup with simpler tooling would be appreciated.
